# Using XSLT to split a collection of objects and redistribute?

Tags: xslt

I need to use XSLT to map values from this format:

```
<Package>
<WorkflowProcesses>
    <WorkflowProcess>            
        <Activities>                
            <Activity Name="First Activity" Id="123">                    
            </Activity>       
            <Activity Name="Second Activity" Id="456">                    
            </Activity> 
            <Activity Name="Third Activity" Id="789">                    
            </Activity> 
        </Activities>
        <Transitions>
            <Transition To="789" From="456" Id="ABC">                
            </Transition>  
            <Transition To="456" From="123" Id="XYZ">                    
            </Transition>            
        </Transitions>
    </WorkflowProcess>
</WorkflowProcesses>
</Package>
```

to this format:

```
<variable type="State">
   <stateId type="Integer">123</stateId>
   <stateName type="String">First Activity</stateName>
   <previousStatesId type="String[]">       
   </previousStatesId>
   <nextStatesId type="String[]">
      <item>456</item>
   </nextStatesId>
</variable>           

<variable type="State">
   <stateId type="Integer">456</stateId>
   <stateName type="String">Second Activity</stateName>
   <previousStatesId type="String[]">
    <item>123</item>
       </previousStatesId>
   <nextStatesId type="String[]">
      <item>789</item>
   </nextStatesId>
</variable>    

<variable type="State">
   <stateId type="Integer">789</stateId>
   <stateName type="String">Third Activity</stateName>
   <previousStatesId type="String[]">
    <item>456</item>
   </previousStatesId>
   <nextStatesId type="String[]">
   </nextStatesId>
</variable>
```

The part that I'm struggling with is to get the values out of the 'Transitions' section and allocate them to the correct area ('nextStatesId' and 'previousStatesId'); everything else is working as expected.

So far, I've been successful mapping the Activity items using this:

```
<xsl:template match="Activities">  
<xsl:apply-templates/>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Activity [@Name]">  
<variable type="State">
    <stateId type="Integer"><xsl:value-of select="@Id"/></stateId>
     <stateName type="String"><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></stateName>
     </variable>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can use this to identify all of the Transition items, then I was going to compare the id of the Transition with the current Activity, but it doesn't work within the template above.  I assume this is because the template doesn't have visibility of the entire XML file and therefore doesn't understand the mapping

```
<xsl:for-each select="Package/WorkflowProcesses/WorkflowProcess/Transitions/Transition">    
      <p>...do some stuff...</p>        
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Normally, if I were coding, I'd just shove them into two lists and then search them.  What I was planning to do here was to just loop through all of the transitions from within each Activity with a simple 'if' statement for the previous / next state id... but that seems to fail.

Does anyone know of another method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the `for-each` inside of your template it will search for a **child** `Package/...` in **Activity**. But there is none.

What you are trying to do here is access the the root node. Therefore put a slash "`/`" before `Package`.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Package/WorkflowProcesses/WorkflowProcess/Transitions/Transition">    
      <p>...do some stuff...</p>        
 </xsl:for-each>
```

However, I would not recommend using `for-each` here. `applay-templates` would fit better.
Try:

```
<xsl:template match="Activity[@Name]">
    <variable type="State">
        <stateId type="Integer">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Id"/>
        </stateId>
        <stateName type="String">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
        </stateName>
        <previousStatesId type="String[]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//Transition[@To =current()/@Id]" 
                                 mode="from" />
        </previousStatesId>
        <nextStatesId type="String[]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//Transition[@From =current()/@Id]" 
                                 mode="to" />
        </nextStatesId>

    </variable>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Transition" mode="from">
    <item>
        <xsl:value-of select="@From"/>
    </item>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Transition" mode="to">
    <item>
        <xsl:value-of select="@To"/>
    </item>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Perfect: also works for multiple transitions to/from the same node which is even better.

Answer (score 1):

This transform seems to do what you ask.

Your *"to this format"* isn't well-formed as it has no root element, so I have added a dummy `<root>` element.

The transform uses keys to access the `Transition` elements by their attributes.

I wonder if you *really* need the space and newline content in your otherwise empty `previousStatesId` and `nextStatesId` output elements? This transform produces self-closing empty elements instead. The change wouldn't be hard to do if you require strict accuracy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="transition-from" match="Transition" use="@From"/>
  <xsl:key name="transition-to" match="Transition" use="@To"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Package/WorkflowProcesses/WorkflowProcess/Activities/Activity"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Activity">
    <xsl:variable name="from-here" select="key('transition-from', @Id)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="to-here" select="key('transition-to', @Id)"/>
    <variable type="State">
      <stateId type="Integer">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Id"/>
      </stateId>
      <stateName type="String">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
      </stateName>
      <previousStatesId type="String[]">
        <xsl:if test="$to-here">
          <item>
            <xsl:value-of select="$to-here/@From"/>
          </item>
        </xsl:if>
      </previousStatesId>
      <nextStatesId type="String[]">
        <xsl:if test="$from-here">
          <item>
            <xsl:value-of select="$from-here/@To"/>
          </item>
        </xsl:if>
      </nextStatesId>
    </variable>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<root>
   <variable type="State">
      <stateId type="Integer">123</stateId>
      <stateName type="String">First Activity</stateName>
      <previousStatesId type="String[]"/>
      <nextStatesId type="String[]">
         <item>456</item>
      </nextStatesId>
   </variable>
   <variable type="State">
      <stateId type="Integer">456</stateId>
      <stateName type="String">Second Activity</stateName>
      <previousStatesId type="String[]">
         <item>123</item>
      </previousStatesId>
      <nextStatesId type="String[]">
         <item>789</item>
      </nextStatesId>
   </variable>
   <variable type="State">
      <stateId type="Integer">789</stateId>
      <stateName type="String">Third Activity</stateName>
      <previousStatesId type="String[]">
         <item>456</item>
      </previousStatesId>
      <nextStatesId type="String[]"/>
   </variable>
</root>
```

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I was looking for, and easy to understand too

Comment: //Edit: actually, it doesn't seem to work for multiple transitions from/to the same Activity, just the first one.  Thanks anyway.  I realise that I didn't specify this with the question so still a good answer! :-)